# How to ignore error after cURL in php and continue to next row in array

Tags: php, curl

My code is below.. using php to take data from SQL and post it using cURL. My question is after cURL encounters an error, is there a way to ignore it (or send it to a log file) and continue with the next line in the array? Currently as soon as it finds an error it's killing it.

```
<?php

// SQL connection stuff...

// fetch data from sql
$sql = "Select * from tablename";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . sqlsrv_error($conn));

// convert result to array
$array = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $array[] = $row;
}       
foreach($array as $data) {
$post = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

//echo $post; //save this for testing later
}


// API url
$url = "www.example.com";

// initiate cURL
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// execute POST
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// display errors
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status."=response"."</br>";

curl_close($ch);

// close connection
sqlsrv_close($conn) 

?>
```

Comment: Your curl request is only going to be executed once regardless of success or failure, as there is no looping construct here at all.

Comment: I'm realizing that now... but not sure why when I just echo it it's showing me all of the results. Before I added the foreach it was only returning the first result so I thought the curl would now loop too but obviously I'm mistaken.

Comment: Ugh, because I've got the foreach in the echo but not the curl... dang I need a nap. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code inside `try {} ... catch {}` to allow you to handle any exceptions:

```
try {
   // your curl execution
} catch (Exception $e) { 
   // log or do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it'd be something easy like that. Quick follow up question if that's ok... it appears to be now that I also have an error in getting it to loop through them in general. If I do an "echo $post" as I have commented out currently I see all of them, but in running the cURL it's only doing the first one still?

Comment: it seemes to me that $array is not array